# Edit session useing session_id or user info

Tags: php, session

I would like to update session variables from another php file using session_id or the user info. Let's say that user is signed in (has session open). 
There also is another file called receive_notification.php
which receives http request from mobile app and gets data from it. I am trying to include these data in user's MemberPage.

```
//receives location updates from the app
<?php
require 'database.php';
require 'model.php';

if(isset($_POST["IMEI"])){
    //collect data
$imei = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'IMEI');
$SessionID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Sessionid');
$latitude = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Lat');
$longitude = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Long');

if(!isset($_SESSION)){
session_id($SessionID);
session_start();
}

//gets phone id
$phoneid = getphoneIdByIMEI($imei);
//gets user's (firstname, lastname, email)
$user = getUserByPhoneID($phoneid);
//echo $latitude ." ".$longtitude;

//trying to update specific user's MemberPage and 
//display $latitude and $longtitude
include('../MemberPage.php');
    }else {echo "nothing";}

?>
```

I am trying to get the user and include $latitude and $longitude in his session, but when I am trying to echo them, they are undefined in MemberPage.php. I am trying to figure out this thing for a while now. Can someone tell me how to find the specific user and include those data in the session ?

Comment: include('../MemberPage.php'); this line write on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with MemberPage.php page , Is it having any syntax error or Are you able to print any data from MemberPage.php page.

Try to check the include path and move the include file in top of the page.

Comment: MemberPage works perfect I can echo all the user info(Firstname lastname email). only problem is that when I try to print longtitude and lat. they are not recognized.